# Best Practices for Deploying a Database in Kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, production

Good afternoon!

I am relatively new to Kubernetes. I would like to ask for your help in knowledge! What is the best way to deploy Postgresql or MySql in kubernetes for production? Suggest articles or resources, I would be very grateful.

I only see examples and information on how to deploy Postgresql dev, very little information on how to set up a production environment. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

We have been running multiple databases on K8s like Elasticsearch, Redis some message brokers so it you can definitely run on Production.

Now i would suggest going with the Operator managed **Database deployment**. As on Production, you might be expecting an **HA**, data replication which you won't be having an idea in depth. **Operator** manages the **deployment** in simple words and do the operation as need.

[Here](https://postgres-operator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is the document to follow for **postgres** operator is has the details on how **CRD**, **stateful sets** volume work together.

Zalando postgres-operator : https://github.com/zalando/postgres-operator

Comparision between available operator : https://blog.palark.com/comparing-kubernetes-operators-for-postgresql/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at [CloudNativePG](https://cloudnative-pg.io/), a fully declarative Kubernetes operator to manage Postgres High Availability Clusters. It is open source, owned by a vendor neutral and openly governed community.

- Homepage: [cloudnative-pg.io](https://cloudnative-pg.io/)
- Overview of capabilities: https://cloudnative-pg.io/documentation/current/operator_capability_levels/

*Disclaimer: I am one of the founders and maintainers of the project.*